Blazor 9 Exception thrown when Registering or Logging in
I create a "Blazor Web App" straight from the template for ASP.NET Core 9, with interactivity set to global WASM and Individual User Accounts. Then, when I try to register, or if I seed the database and try to log in, I get the following error:
Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.

This occurs in IdentityRedirectManager.RedirectTo(string? uri) at navigationManager.NavigateTo(uri);
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Does this happen in without debugging mode?

This is a known open issue.
The most basic solution is to uncheck the Break when this exception type is user-unhadled in the Exception Settings:

